Bitbucket pipeline failed due to repo checkout permission issue - Ansible playbook steps involved
I am getting the below error when my Bitbucket pipeline fails. I am creating a new AWS AMI using the Packer tool. I am using an Ansible playbook to create a customized AMI. I modified permissions for SSH keys. I am fetching keys from the SSM parameter store. (600 for private key, 400 for public key). I connected to the created AWS instance and copied the key to the created instance; post that, I tried to check out the repo. But during this step my pipeline failed. Below is the error message.
amazon-ebs.this: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:companyname/network-monorepo.git -h refs/heads/2022.RTT_29, "msg": "Warning:********@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.",
"rc": 128, "stderr": "Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Load key \"/root/.ssh/bitbucket\": error in libcrypto
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
", "stderr_lines": ["Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.", "Load key \"/root/.ssh/bitbucket\": error in libcrypto", "git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).", "fatal: Could not read from remote repository.", "", "Please make sure you have the correct access rights", "and the repository exists."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}


Have you added the public key to Bitbucket?

When I tried to add public key on bitbucket it says "Someone has already added that SSH key."

Then you'll need to use a different key.

Now I tried with a new key. Still, I am facing the permission issue. Here is the script i am using for bitbucket pipeline and ansible playbook. can you please suggest. In the ansible playbook steps i added only upto clone part, on that step i am facing my issue.
https://github.com/Venkateshd279/packer_image_build-.git
